# css-loader not importing .css file returning empty object

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-style-loader, css-loader

Importing style from css files. Returning empty object. Seems css-loader is not working correctly. Can anyone help me on this. Please find the reference files below

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react'   
import style from './header.css'

console.log(style) // Returning empty object

export default class Header extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    return(
      <header className = {style.header}>
        This is header component
      </header>
    )
  }
}
```

**./header.css**

```
.header {
  background: #007DC6;
}
```

**./webpack.config.js**

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
}, {
  test: /\.css$/,
  include: /node_modules/,
  loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I wonder if this is perhaps you are not using [css-modules](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/#css-modules). The example you are showing there is an example of implementing the css-modules feature of the loader.

Perhaps try adding the `?modules` query to your `css-loader` definition.

Comment: adding ?modules query to css-loader solve the issue. Appreciate the answer

Comment: Can you show how exactly use modules, I am facing the same problem?. Thanks.

Comment: @GopinathShiva Can you please show us what you did to solve this?

Comment: @darksoulsong , I have added css-loader query to the webpack module definition for "test : /\.css$/" like this,  `loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader?modules=true&camelCase=true']`

Comment: @GopinathShiva Worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

You can fix your problem with three ways :

#1:
Replace `'css-loader'` with `'css-loader?modules=true&camelCase=true'`

#2:
Do old school like this :

##index.js

```
import React from 'react'   
import './header.css'

export default class Header extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    return(
      <header className="header">
        This is header component
      </header>
    )
  }
}
```

#3:
use [babel-plugin-react-css-modules](https://github.com/gajus/babel-plugin-react-css-modules) or [React CSS Modules](https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules)

Comment: I'm trying the 2nd method. But I can't seem to make it work. If I do import styles from file and the use stles.classname then it work. I'm new to react. What exactly I'm doing wrong?

Comment: look @RohanShenoy, in the second method all styles in `header.css` file will attach to the final project and it's not modular, I suggest you follow this page: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet

Comment: Hi @Mohammad. Thanks a lot for the reply. Yes you're right I got the issue because it was modular.