# When using css-loader, imported style object is empty

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-loader

I'm trying to use css-loader to import styles from style sheets for each react component, but the object I import is empty.  See code:

Header.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './Header.css';

const header = () => {
    console.log('classes obj', classes);

    return (
        <div className={classes.Header}>
            <h1>Title Goes Here</h1>
        </div>
    )
}


export default header;
```

And here is my Header.css file:

```
.Header {
    background-color:  rgb(49, 118, 197);
}
```

And here is a snippet of my webpack config for dev:

```
test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
              require.resolve('style-loader'),
              {
                loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
                options: {
                  importLoaders: 1,
                  modules: true,
                  localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
                },
              },
```

And a snippet of my webpack config for prod:

```
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
      Object.assign(
        {
          fallback: {
            loader: require.resolve('style-loader'),
            options: {
              hmr: false,
            },
          },
          use: [
            {
              loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
              options: {
                importLoaders: 1,
                minimize: true,
                sourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap,
                modules: true,
                localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]',
              },
            },
```

A similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41296757/css-loader-not-importing-css-file-returning-empty-object) but the webpack config looks too different to implement the solution.

You can see in my Header.js I'm console.logging the classes obj I'm importing, but it's an empty object.

Any clues?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ok an answer for other silly people like me.  Restart your build process after you install css-loader.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this {
  test: /.css$/,
  loader: 'style!css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]**[local]_**[hash:base64:5]' 
}

Comment: Thank you John but simply restarting my dev server fixed it.  Silly error on my part.

Comment: Happy to know :)

Answer (score -1):

Update your `css-loader` and `style-loader`